# Proving $n! \ge 2^{n-1 }$for all $n\ge1 $by mathematical Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Im trying to solve the following question

---

[image]

---

In the second step  where do they get $k!=2^k-1?$

Comment: They never wrote $k! = 2^k - 1$, or even $k!=2^{k-1}$. They only used the induction hypothesis $k!\geq 2^{k-1}$.

Comment: They wrote $k! = 2^{k-1}$, which is the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @CarlHeckman No they did not. Not with equality.

Comment: It's the induction hypothesis.

Comment: That's right; I should have said $k! \ge 2^{k-1}$. I corrected one mistake but not another.

Comment: @Yash Malik can you fix your edit please

Comment: @techno-Can you prove $n!>2^n$ for all $n\geq  4$?Then I can explain it to you.

Comment: @Yash Malik With due respect,Please stop editing if you dont know what you are doing.

Comment: @techno I am sorry for that but now it's okay!

Comment: @YashMalik Thanks :) its okay now.No probs.

Answer (score 1):

In the induction step, they say "Suppose that $k! \ge 2^{k-1}$ for some $k \ge 1$."

That then allows them to say "$(k+1)\,k! \ge (k+1)\,2^{k-1}$", multiplying both sides of the inequality by the positive $(k+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example...similar to your problem..

Prove $n!>2^n$   $(n \geq4)$
Prove it at first for any $n \geq 4$.

Assume it true for some $k$. let it be true $k!>2^k$

Now we try to prove it true for $k+1$.
We have to prove $(k+1)!>2^{k+1}$.

We know $2^{k+1}$=$2^k*2$.

Also,we know $(k+1)!=k!*(k+1).$ We also assumed earlier $k!>2^k$.

So, we can write $k!(k+1)>2^k*2$ [Since,$k>4 ,k+1>4>2$ which is in the RHS and $k!>2^k$ as we assumed earlier].

Hope this helps you to understand the problem and solve it in a similar way.